# Get likes from instagram ad post via API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I have deal with problem. I want to load likes from ad posts with API. For this I use 2 methods:

1. https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/D?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN with this method I get media-id of record
2. https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN with this method I’m trying to get likes, but receive error, that media-id is incorrect.

How to get likes from ad posts?

Answer (score 4):

Well if it's saying your media id is not correct then its right.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Because this is the endpoint for likes in the instagram official [Official Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/).

**Confusion**
Since it's a year i've been working on instagram API extensively, there is a tiny chance that you're taking the wrong media id.
if you're having `media_id` like this `1442272751838402596_2344486445` this id is composed of two things and separated by _ (underscore).

```
POST_ID: 1442272751838402596
OWNER_ID: 2344486445
```

So becareful when you're getting the likes for a post using media ID.

Comment: I'm trying to get likes from post like this:  https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/1403871831044076085/likes?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN and response with error. With your post-id ok.